# Error using gcrypt on function gcry_cipher_encrypt C++

Tags: c++, linux, libgcrypt

I'm trying to use gcrypt to make a simple cryptography a txt file. When I executes the command `gcry_cipher_encrypt` i receive the follow errors:

```
gcry_strsource => User defined source 1
gcry_strerror => Invalid length
```

This occurs when I use the content of one txt file, if I hardcode the text content in the code this function works, what is the possible cause?

**Text file content**

```
test test test test test
```

**Crypt code:**

```
void myEncrypt::aesEncrypt(char *txtInput, int txtInputSize, char *txtOutput){

    gcry_error_t     gcryError;
    gcry_cipher_hd_t gcryCipherHd;
    size_t           index;


    size_t keyLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_keylen(GCRY_CIPHER);
    size_t blkLength = gcry_cipher_get_algo_blklen(GCRY_CIPHER);
    //char * txtBuffer = "123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ 123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ";
    char * txtBuffer = txtInput;
    size_t txtLength = strlen(txtBuffer)+1; // string plus termination
    char * encBuffer = (char *)malloc(txtLength);
    char * outBuffer = (char *)malloc(txtLength);
    char * aesSymKey = "one test AES key"; // 16 bytes
    char * iniVector = "a test ini value"; // 16 bytes

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_open(
        &gcryCipherHd, // gcry_cipher_hd_t *
        GCRY_CIPHER,   // int
        GCRY_C_MODE,   // int
        0);            // unsigned int
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_open failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_open    worked\n");

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_setkey(gcryCipherHd, aesSymKey, keyLength);
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_setkey failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_setkey  worked\n");

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_setiv(gcryCipherHd, iniVector, blkLength);
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_setiv failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_setiv   worked\n");

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_encrypt(
        gcryCipherHd, // gcry_cipher_hd_t
        encBuffer,    // void *
        txtLength,    // size_t
        txtBuffer,    // const void *
        txtLength);   // size_t
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_encrypt failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_encrypt worked\n");

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_setiv(gcryCipherHd, iniVector, blkLength);
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_setiv failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_setiv   worked\n");

    gcryError = gcry_cipher_decrypt(
        gcryCipherHd, // gcry_cipher_hd_t
        outBuffer,    // void *
        txtLength,    // size_t
        encBuffer,    // const void *
        txtLength);   // size_t
    if (gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_decrypt failed:  %s/%s\n",
               gcry_strsource(gcryError),
               gcry_strerror(gcryError));
        return;
    }
    printf("gcry_cipher_decrypt worked\n");

    printf("keyLength = %d\n", keyLength);
    printf("blkLength = %d\n", blkLength);
    printf("txtLength = %d\n", txtLength);
    printf("aesSymKey = %s\n", aesSymKey);
    printf("iniVector = %s\n", iniVector);
    printf("txtBuffer = %s\n", txtBuffer);

    printf("encBuffer = ");
    for (index = 0; index<txtLength; index++)
        printf("%02X", (unsigned char)encBuffer[index]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("outBuffer = %s\n", outBuffer);

    // clean up after ourselves
    gcry_cipher_close(gcryCipherHd);
    free(encBuffer);
    free(outBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... I don't know libgcrypt, but...

In [this page](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-cipher-handles.html), in the description of the `gcry_cipher_encrypt()` function, I read

> Depending on the selected algorithms and encryption mode, the length of the buffers must be a multiple of the block size.

If I understand well, you're using AES as algorithm so, according various sources ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_%28cryptography%29), by example), the block size for AES is 16 bytes.

If you look at the original `txtBuffer`, you can see that was of 63 bytes (9 numbers, 26+26 letters, 2 spaces), so (adding +1 for the terminal zero) `txtLength` was 64, an exact multiple of 16.

Your text is of 25 bytes, so your `texLength` if 26, that isn't a multiple of 16.

En passant: you're using C++, so I strongly suggest to avoid `malloc()` and use `new []` instead; or (better, IMHO) `std::string` with `reserve()`, `c_str()` and `data()`.

I suppose you should use `txtBuffer` as an intermediate allocated buffer.

Using the `new []` solution, I suppose you should modify you code in this way

```
std::size_t txtLength = strlen(txtInput)+1; // from txtInput, not txtBuffer

if ( 0U != (txtLength & 0xfU) )
   txtLength += 0x10U - (txtLength & 0xfU);

char * txtBuffer = new char[txtLength];
char * encBuffer = new char[txtLength];
char * outBuffer = new char[txtLength];

std::strcpy(txtBuffer, txtInput);
```

p.s.: caution, code not tested.

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Great observation @max66, I have changed the size of the file to multiple of 16 and have removed the "+1" on the calculation of the size file now everything works well. Tks